# Android multi client socket chat application

Tags: android, android-adapter, asyncsocket

I have developed chat application using socket for multi client and multi user
chat like whats app but my problem is suppose when i send the chat message to A it will shown to all user.I want the separation like if A is chat with B then it will not shown to all.
                   I have created the Base adapter and Array list to store the message. how i separate the window for all user one one chat like whats app.
please Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: `when i send the chat message to A it will shown to all user.`. No. Only when you programmed it to do so. So remove that code and you are done.